# Can we use Apache Mina ( NIO: Non blocking IO) client to connect to BIO ( Blocking I/O) server

Tags: android, tcp, nio, apache-mina

I am suppose to maintain multiple TCP connections (with different servers) in an android App.These servers are written in C++ and I am guessing it is based on traditional blocking i/o.

I have to keep listening asynchronously to the messages from these TCP connections, I am planning to use Apache Mina only at client.

But can I use Apache Mina ( a Non blocking i/o framework) only as client and connect to a traditional  blocking I/O TCP server environment ?

If not Apache Mina, Is there any library in android to manage listening to messages from multiple TCP connections in android ?